# Set Form to Pristine without clearing data

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form that displays a list of `<input type="text">` elements. They all share a common save button which is disabled until the form becomes dirty. Then, once the user clicks the save button, the data will be submitted to the server. If the server successfully saved the data, I want to reset the form to a pristine state, but I want to keep all of the data in the form so the user can edit the data further if they so choose.

After searching, I have found the `NgForm.reset()` method. While this does set the form to pristine, it unfortunately also clears out the form. The reset method does seem to have a value parameter, but I can't seem to find out what it does. Nevertheless, I don't want the data cleared out.

I have also tried `myForm.pristine = true` as well, but this causes a reload of the page for some reason.

[Here is a plunkr demonstrating the problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/wf9Ggiue5Xc8vNRXmZ6O?p=preview).

Answer (score 198, accepted):

What you're looking for is `myForm.markAsPristine()`.

Comment: So, can I apply markAsPristine() property to a specific control?

Comment: The syntax that worked for me is `myForm.markAsPristine()`.

Comment: Also be careful as it will set dirty to false internally

Answer (score 39):

At the moment I can suggest two possible solutions.
First one is really close to what you've suggested, as form's `reset` method has following signature and accepts form value as a first argument:

```
//@angular/forms/src/model.d.ts:
reset(value?: any, {onlySelf}?: { onlySelf?: boolean; }): void;
```

In the submit handler, we will capture a copy of the last state:

```
const { myForm: { value: formValueSnap } } = this;
```

And do the reset itself:

```
this.myForm.reset(formValueSnap, false);
```

Another option from the times, when there was no possibility to reset form, is to create a helper method, which will mark each control as `pristine` and will keep the data. It can be called in the same submit helper in place of the resetting.

```
private _markFormPristine(form: FormGroup | NgForm): void {
    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(control => {
        form.controls[control].markAsPristine();
    });
}
```

Link to the updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pwIuAWBJG5oITk9zuhVT?p=preview).

Comment: How to achieve this in template-driven-form??

Comment: `_markFormPristine` won't operate on nested controls; `form.controls` can have more `FormGroup` objects in it with their own controls - `form.controls.foo.controls.bar.markAsPristine()`.

Answer (score 17):

If you happen to be using Template-Driven forms and you have something like this in your component: 
`@ViewChild('myForm') myform: NgForm;`

I've found that the `markAsPristine()` is a function on the form property of your form. So it would be `this.myform.form.markAsPristine()`.

Just thought I'd add this in case others come across `markAsPristine()` as not being defined.

Comment: instead of type `any`, I'd suggest to use the proper type `NgForm`. Example: `@ViewChild('myForm') myform: NgForm;`

Comment: Can I apply markAsPristine() property to a specific control @Mike?

Answer (score 6):

When using Angular's [**reactive forms**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), you can use **markAsPristine()** on the FormGroup:

```
export class MyPage

  // Your form group
  public formGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      // Add your form controls here
    });
  }

  onSubmitForm() {
    // Get form value and save data on the server
    // ...

    this.formGroup.markAsPristine(); // <=== Mark form group as pristine
  }
}
```

See also: documentation for [AbstractControl.markAsPristine()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsPristine). Note: FormGroup is a subclass of AbstractControl. It will mark all children of the FormGroup as pristine.

Answer (score 3):

I think i solve done this on my method:

`form.controls['contato'].reset();`

Comment: This clears the data in that specific control and marks it as pristine, which does not match the behavior that the original question is wanting.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't found a markAsPristine() in the `form` property, but I found a `_pristine` property, `this.myForm['form']._pristine` which can be set to `true`.

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: ElementRef;
this.myForm['form']._pristine = true;
```

Answer (score -4):

To reset the form:

```
this.form.reset();
```

Comment: That will clear the data