# How to reset a form control to pristine in Angular?

Tags: angular

If I have the below form control,

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="First Name" type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName">
</mat-form-field>
```

how do I reset its state back to ng-pristine from the component?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690371/angular-2-set-form-to-pristine-without-clearing-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690371/angular-2-set-form-to-pristine-without-clearing-data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will mark every ngModel as pristine in your form. If you want to mark pristine a specific one, simply put a condition inside forEach loop

```js
class //bla bla bla {
@ViewChildren(NgModel) fields: QueryList<NgModel>;

// stuffs

checkErrors() {
  this.fields.forEach(model => {
    model.control.markAsPristine();
  }
};
```

If you want to reset your value, just add `model.control.reset();` before the pristine marker

Comment: It can't find my fields (I use [formFroup] and formControlName).

Comment: The @ViewChildren can be used for not NgModel only, so you can specify the html identificator for yours formgroups